# .Net - Parsing an XML with a definition node

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, linq-to-xml

I am trying to parse an XML document in C# where the first node defines a definition for attributes that will appear in a future node.

As a simplified example, consider this XML:

```
<AudioTrack>
    <Tracks>
        <Track Name="Name1" Path="....." />
        <Track Name="Name2" Path="....." />
        <Track Name="Name3" Path="....." />
        <Track Name="Name4" Path="....." />
        <Track Name="Name5" Path="....." />
    </Tracks>

    <TrackInformation Track="Name1" Attribute1="xx">
        <TrackInformation Track="Name2" Attribute1="yy" Attribute2="zz" />
        <TrackInformation Track="Name3" Attribute1="yy">
            <TrackInformation Track="Name4" Attribute1="yy" />
            <TrackInformation Track="Name5" Attribute1="yy" />
        </TrackInformation>
    </TrackInformation>
</AudioTrack>
```

Simply explained, this is a definition for an audio track layering multiple sub-tracks on top of each other to creating a final, mixed output.

My simplified classes are as follows:

```
public class AudioTrack
{
    public Tracks Tracks { get; set; }
    public TrackInformation MainTrack { get; set; }
}

public class Tracks
{
    public List<Track> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Track
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public Track(string name, string path)
    {
        Name = name;
        Path = path;
    }
}

public class TrackInformation
{
    public List<TrackInformation> SubTracks { get; set; }
    public Track Track { get; set; }
    public string Attribute1 { get; set; }
    public string Attribute2 { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to parse / serialize this such that each `TrackInformation` gets the actual `Track` that was defined in the earlier node.

My only idea so far was to use *LINQtoXML* to pull the tracks into a Dictionary and create my own parser for the `TrackInformation`, but I'm hoping there is still some way to use XML Serializer or a better way to do this I am not aware of that would save me having to deal with recursion through the `TrackInformation` nodes, creating the Dictionary, etc.

Comment: I am seeing at least 4 classes for that example.... `AudioTrack`, `Track`, `Tracks` and `TrackInformation`

Comment: @zaggler, you're right - Updated accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, can you change that XML definition? If not, unfortunately you'd have to handle the parsing/deserializing as you only know how they relate to one another, it's not clear in the XML at this point and standard ways will not accomplish what you need.

Comment: I could, but this structure allows for decoupling the definition of paths and the actual mixing of them (so, the mixing element never needs to be updated), so my partners liked this concept. If it's too hard to do it otherwise, it is possible to change it, though - Just hoping there is a way to do this without going down that route.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, you'd need to handle these scenarios yourself. It's a little bit of work, but nothing to complicated.

Comment: So, basically, the way I was going, LINQtoXML - Populate a Dictionary, then use that within the <TrackInformation> parser? ANY smarter ideas would really be appreciated! :)

Comment: Yes, that would work. If I can think of something better I will post here.